# Advence .htaccess redirect with one exception

Tags: .htaccess, exception, redirect

I need help with .htaccess redirect.
There is a lot of simmilar answers, but did not find the one for my case.

I ve got this config:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Rewrite to index.php if not file or directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now I need redirection for all url but not for 'news_list'

This work for all redirections:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

For exception I should use:
**RewriteRule !^news_list($|/) https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]**

This works - 'news_list' do not redirect, but problem is, that than '/news_list' doesn't work (because it need point to 'index.php?url=news_list'.

So I need kinda mix of all configs above, but no luck.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite everything to new host except for /news_list...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news_list(?:$|/)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,END]

# Rewrite to index.php if not file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for your help and all provide informations.
I try code, but it always redirect to www.newsite.com
I try with 302, & 301.
Meanwhile I create this redirect in index.php :)

For now it works, but it is ugly solution.

Tnx again for all informations - I will study your code and test a little more.

We have that bad practice, to solve that kind of problems in .htaccess - I guess because of lack of knowledge.

Comment: I understood from your question that you indeed _wanted_ to redirect everything to the new host name. Except for `https://oldsite.com/news_list/something` for which the redirection to `/index.php` should get applied. That is _not_ the case? Then you need to revise your question so that others can understand what it is that you _actually_ want.

Comment: You understand correctly - I want to redirect everything to new host name, but not https://oldsite.com/news_list/something & https://oldsite.com/news_list

But solution redirect all sites (including https.../news_list/something) :)

Comment: No, sorry. above solution does _not_ redirect request to `/news_list...`. If it does for you then you either implemented not what is shown above, or have another redirection rule in place or you are simply using at a cached result. Consider what I wrote about the dangers of http status 301 for a redirection...

Comment: Strange. Maybe there is more to it (some stupid configuration on server, that I don't have access). Thank you soo much for all your help.

Comment: You can check it separate from your site: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Sir you are genius. (of course it works) :)
I finally understand where problem was (^/news_list). Of course on my DEV it doesn't work... Grrr.

You are life saver!
Thank you soo much!

Comment: Sounds like you have a different setup in your development environment than what you described in your question. That happens. Glad you sorted it out. Have fun!

Comment: Yea.. You are right. I sorted out, tnx to you :). Thanks again